# What does this sentence actually mean?

Tags: translation

This is from an interview in a magazine

希望を満ち、つねに未来の先の先のさらにその先を見据えて真っ直ぐ進んでいるような人にはとても憧れている

I'm trying to understand this sentence but it's confusing for me especially the part "未来の先の先のさらにその先を見据えて"

What I understand right now is "I admire people who are full of hope and keep moving forward and looking beyond the future ahead." Can anyone please help me understand. Thank you.

Comment: 希望**を**満ち may be a typo. I think it is 希望**に**満ち or 希望を**持**ち.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 未来の先の先のさらにその先を見据えて

"見据{みす}えて" is a continuous form or 連用形{れんようけい} of "見据える" as you know, so I'll explain (A).

> (A) 未来の先の先のさらにその先を見据える

"先{さき}" has various meanings, and it has the meaning with "次 *next to*", "向こう *over*" or "超えて　*beyond*" in (A).
Therefore "未来｛みらい｝の先" means "beyond the future".
"さらに" is written "更に" in *kanji* and it means "furthermore" or "still more".

> (B) 未来を見据える
>   (C) 未来の先を見据える
>   (D) 未来の先の先を見据える

(B) means "look ahead" or "look into the future".
When you use (C), (D) and (A) instead of (B), the degree of "furthermore/beyond/ahead" to (B) will be gradually emphasized.
In the above explanation, I think that the **degree** is difficult to understand as actual feeling, so I would like to explain the nuance of "先の先" in another example.

In a game in which pieces are alternately moved like *shogi* or chess, to predict the move of a piece of the opponent against your move is called "相手｛あいて｝の手｛て｝/指手{さして}を読｛よ｝む *predict the move of the opponent*" or "先{さき}を読む lit. *read the future/hereafter*".
Your predicting one move of a piece by the opponent is called "一手{いって}先｛さき｝を読む lit. *read next one hand*". Likewise, to predict until the opponent's second move of a piece is called "二手｛にて｝先を読む lit. *read next two hands* or "先の先を読む *read ahead twice*".
You can say like "三手{さんて}先を読む", "先の先の先を読む" or "先の先のさらに先を読む".

I think that you can see the accuracy of prediction increases as the number of 先 increases.